# Get list of coupons code for a cart id

Tags: magento2, api, coupon

Is there any **API** in magento to get **list of all coupons** appreciable to a corresponding cart id.

can we **get sale rules** for a **cart id** and then **find coupon through it**

Comment: Hi if you got the solution please share I am having same problem

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$userData = array("username" => "admin", "password" => "153258ww");
$ch = curl_init("http://website.com/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Length: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));
$token = curl_exec($ch);
$request = "http://website.com/rest/V1/carts/{cartId}/coupons";
$ch = curl_init($request);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r(json_decode($result));
?>
```